# Не работает пульт на arduino

Tags: arduino

Пытаюсь собрать пульт на arduino, который будет записывать сигналы с других пультов и передавать их (примерно как [здесь](https://lesson.iarduino.ru/page/urok-35-universalnyy-ik-pult-distancionnogo-upravleniya), но с одной кнопкой). Немного переписав код с сайта по ссылке и запустив его, я увидел, что полученные сигналы с одной и той же кнопки пульта различаются и ни разу переданный сигнал не сработал (не включил телевизор и т.п.). В прочности контактов и в том что излучатель что-то передаёт я уверен. Почему не работает и как исправить?

мой код:

```
#include <iarduino_IR_RX.h>                                                                      
#include <iarduino_IR_TX.h>                                                                      
const uint8_t  PinButton1= 2;                                                                    const uint8_t  PinButton7= 8;                                                                    iarduino_IR_RX IR_Read   ( 9);                                                                   iarduino_IR_TX IR_Write  (10);                                                                   const uint8_t  PinBuzzer= 11;                                                                    uint8_t        ValButton= 0,abc;                                                                     long long       ValCode;                                                                          char           ValProtocol[26];                                                                  
void setup(){
    IR_Read.begin();
    IR_Write.begin();
    pinMode(2, INPUT);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  while(true)
  {
    if (IR_Write.protocol(ValProtocol)){
      IR_Write.send(ValCode, true);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);delay(50);digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    }
    if(IR_Read.check())
    {
      strcpy(ValProtocol, IR_Read.protocol());
      Serial.print(ValProtocol);
      delay(50);
      Serial.print(' ');
      delay(50);
      for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
        Serial.print(ValProtocol[i],HEX);
      delay(50);
      Serial.print(' ');
      delay(50);
      Serial.print(IR_Read.data);
      delay(50);
      Serial.print(' ');
      delay(50);
      /*Serial.print(IR_Read.data,HEX);
      delay(50);
      Serial.print('\t');
      delay(50);
      Serial.println(IR_Read.data,BIN);
      delay(50);*/
    }
  }
  //Serial.println(1);
}

void myDelay()
{
  for(long long i=0;i<100000000;i++)
  {
    i=i;
  }
}

String itos(long long n)
{
  String ans="";char buf;int sz=0;
  while(n!=0)
  {
    ans+=char(n%10+'0');
    n/=10;
    sz++;
  }
  for(int i=0;i*2<sz;i++)
  {
    buf=ans[i];
    ans[i]=ans[sz-i-1];
    ans[sz-i-1]=buf;
    //Serial.print(i);
  }
  //ans[0]='1';
  return ans;
}
```

Вывод в Serial monitor:

```
BeLLYoLJLWMPWIMK@@@@@@@B` 2704
BeLLYoLIMVMPVIML@@@@@@@B` 2704 
BeH@@NLILVLFVILL@@@@@@@@@ 16 
BeMAv[LIMVMPVIMK@@@@@@@C@ 6800 
BeI@@KLJLVMHVIML@@@@@@@@@ 144 
BeLLYpKKKXKPXJKJ@@@@@@@B` 2704 
BeLLYoKJLWMPWIMK@@@@@@@B` 2704 
BeLLYoLJMVMPVIML@@@@@@@B` 2704 
CeI@@EKJLWLFWJLK@@@@@@@@@ 480 
BeLLYoLKKVMPVIMK@@@@@@@B` 2704 
BeLLYoLIMVMPVIML@@@@@@@B` 2704 
BeH@@SLJLVLFVILL@@@@@@@@@ 144 
CeI@YPKKJWKFWKKJ@@@@@@@C@ 480 
BeMMYFMKLVMPVIML@@@Op@A@ 2704 
BeI@@JMJLVMHVIML@@@@@@@@@ 144 
BeL@@XKILVLNVILK@@@@@@@@@ 2704 
BeMMY_LJLVMPVIML@@@@@@@B@ 6800 
BeI@@JLIMVMHVIML@@@@@@@@@ 144 
BeMMYCLJLVMPVIMK@@@Op@A@ 2704 
BeMMYBLJLVMPVIMK@@@Op@A@ 2704 
BeI@@KLJMVMHVIML@@@@@@@@@ 144 
BeL@@WLJLVMNVIML@@@@@@@@@ 2704 
BeJ@@MLILVMJVIML@@@@@@@@@ 144 
BeLLYnLJLVMPVIMK@@@@@@@B` 2704 
BeH@@QLIMVLFVIML@@@@@@@@@ 144 
BeM@@YKJLVMPVIML@@@@@@@@@ 6800 
BeLLYnMJLVMPVIML@@@@@@@B` 2704 
BeLLYpKJKXLPXJLJ@@@@@@@B` 2704
```

[image: схема]

Comment: Для отладки электроники кроме кода нужны еще фотки монтажа в хайрезе и схема.

Comment: монтаж в хайрезе это что?

Comment: Нужно сфотографировать устройство резко и в высоком разрешении со всех сторон.

Comment: @gbg не перебарщиваете? )

Comment: @Kromster  играя в 20 вопросов можно неделю догадываться, что автор повесил ИК приемник на двухметровый провод, или еще как-то интересно накосячил в монтаже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь получилось, причём что я не менял схему. Проблема была в коде.

выкладываю рабочий код:

```
#include <IRremote.h> // подключаем библиотеку
 
int ledPin = 13; // светодиод
int reciverPin = 11; // пин, к котрому подключен ИК-приемник
IRrecv irrecv(reciverPin);
IRsend sender(10);
uint32_t res;
decode_results results;
IRData* dt;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sender.begin(10,1,LED_BUILTIN);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // запуск приемника
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}
  
void loop() {
  // постоянно считываем данные с приемника
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    // выводим в консольку, что получили, число в 16-ричном виде
    res=results.value;
    Serial.println(res, HEX);
    // проверяем сигналы - и если это те, что нам нужны, то вкл или выкл светодиод
    dt=irrecv.read();
    irrecv.resume(); // готовы принимать следующий сигнал
  }
  if(res!=0)
  {
    sender.write(dt,1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас неправильно подключен ИК приемник. Правильная схема включает в себя резистор и конденсатор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ситуация не изменилась

Comment: Нужно ли подклчать по другому приёмник VS1838B?